# Ubuntu 20 - how to create platform agnostic packages architecture=all specifying dependencies on packages with native architecture

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, debian

I am creating platform agnostic debian package on Ubuntu 20 and Ubuntu 22 -  with an intention to install on both ARM and AMD64 processor architecture. My debian packages have depndencies on other packages
Take example of control file of one of my packages

```
Package: my-package
Version: 1.2.3
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: allowed
Essential: no
Priority: optional
Pre-Depends:  openjdk-11-jdk:any
Depends: 
Maintainer: yours truely
Description: This is architecture agnostic package
```

This package has dependency on other packages - like open-jdk  for example

However when I attempt to install "my-package" on an arm server I get following error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
apt install my-package
my-package : PreDepends: openjdk-11-jdk:any but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The package open-jdk is installed (see below), but that is native "arm64" architecture  and so it isnt being considered for dependency resolution

```
apt list --installed |grep openjdk-11-jdk
openjdk-11-jdk/focal-updates,focal-security,now 11.0.20.1+1-0ubuntu1~20.04 arm64 
[installed]
```

So my question is as follows
**How do I sepcify the dependencies in  my-package control file to allow dependencies of  my package that has "Architecture: all"  to be met with available packages of the native architecture **

I thought that the ":any" suffix added to package names in the clause pre-depends would do the trick  ( see below)
" Pre-Depends:  openjdk-11-jdk:any"
(Shouldnt this allow the dependencies to be met by package of any architecture including the "amd64" architecture?)

In my experience so far that does not seem to be Happenning.
The apt installer is looking for packages with "all" architecture in order to resolve dependencies and does NOT resolve dependencies with packages with amd64 architecture

Should I specify something like - multiple entries for same package with a differnt suffix for different architectures ?

```
Pre-Depends:  openjdk-11-jdk:amd64[amd64], openjdk-11-jdk:arm64[arm64]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Best regards

Yogesh